# Can someone help me visualize this example about different screens sizes?

Tags: android, screen, pixel, screen-resolution, android-screen

I always have difficulties when it comes to supporting multiple screens on Android and completely understand the concepts like dpi etc. Thus, I decided to study it one more time from the beginning. I saw this example in [Android developer web site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> The characteristics that define a device's generalized screen size and
>   density are independent from each other. For example, a **WVGA
>   high-density** screen is considered a **normal size** screen because its
>   physical size is about the same as the T-Mobile G1 (Android's first
>   device and baseline screen configuration). On the other hand, a **WVGA
>   medium-density** screen is considered a **large size screen**. Although it
>   offers the same resolution (the same number of pixels), the WVGA
>   medium-density screen has a lower screen density, meaning that each
>   pixel is physically larger and, thus, the entire screen is larger than
>   the baseline (normal size) screen.

I cannot understand how these two devices have the **same resolution** and the **same physical size** but **different densities**.

If they have **different densities** and **same physical size** shouldn't they have **different resolutions** thus **different number of physical pixels**?

--

Can someone draw an **illustration** for this and these type of concepts? I have a really hard time **visualizing** these things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot understand how these two devices have the same resolution and
>   the same physical size but different densities.

They don't have the same physical size, one is said to be **normal** size and the other to be **large** size so it is not surprising for them to have different density if they have the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

With 1600+ android models even after they are categorized in few Screen size and a few DPI's its very difficult to manage layouts.. i suggest that you just concentrate on designing layouts w.r.t to screen size and then create views as Resized Views to neglect density effects.

**[Here is the Documentation for Supporting Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)**

Once you have created your layouts Resize the Views .. You can create a Custom View or resize on its onMeasure();